# Javascript XMLHttpRequest() is not posting data

Tags: javascript

I have my javascript here on `checkTests.php`, which is a function as follows

```
        function confirmedUpload(){
            //Make the button so it can't be clicked again
            document.getElementById('confirmUpload').setAttribute("disabled", true);

            //This is the data we are posting
            var postData = JSON.stringify(<?php echo $uploadJSON; ?>);

            //This bit works OK and I see the string of JSON printed in the console.
            console.log(postData);

            //Create an XMLHttpRequestObject
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "/uploadTests.php", true);

            xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
            xhr.send(postData);

            //Wait for the page to respond.
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
                {
                    console.log(this.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
```

which I would expect to post the data `postData` to the page `uploadTests.php` and then return the `array(data)` from the `uploadTests.php` page in the console.

But what actually happens is that the post request is made, I see the output `console.log(postData);` from the javascript, but then when `uploadTests.php` returns the value, all I get is `array()  0` and there's no data.

contents of `uploadTests.php` is:

```
<?php

    print_r($_POST);
    echo '   ' . sizeof($_POST);

?>
```

why does `uploadTests.php` think that the $_POST was blank?

Comment: What is in $uploadJSON? You may rather want to try sending a hardcoded string first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to set your `Content Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for PHP to read the `$_POST` superglobal array. Otherwise the content appears in the PHP standard input body which is retrievable via `php://input`. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) for more details.

**EDIT:**

If you can't change the content type, you'll need to read the data from the `php://input` stream which will retrieve the request's content body.

Comment: "I believe that you need to set your Content Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded" — That's no good if your content isn't application/x-www-form-urlencoded!

Comment: I regret to inform you that changing the content type did not make a difference :/

Comment: @Quentin Then the OP needs to read from the standard input stream `php://input`...

Comment: @HarveyFletcher See the updated _edit_.